# How to work with two rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.6 in my professional projects.
I decide to create a personal APP and host it on Hostgator but it only supports Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.18.

I already install the old Ruby version using Rbenv and the desired Rails version, but I can't create the APP using the old Rails version.

I tried to first create a folder and create a Gemfile inside specifying the rails versions but I don't know how to create a new APP.

How can I create older Rails APPs?

Comment: remember that rails2 is incompatible with rails 3+ projects. So it doesn't make sense to use rails2 at this point of time. Use other hosting services like Heroku/OpenShift/AMZN etc. which use newer versions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your provider/hoster only supports ruby 1.8.7 (released 8 years ago) and rails 2.3.18 (last security update 2 years ago) you should just search for another hoster. Both of them have been deprecated years ago and do not get any security updates anymore.